# Interpretation of Keras training and improving accuracy/consistency

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I have finished my first NN (pretty exciting) and have started tweaking in hopes of improving results.

```
Epoch 1/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 69.2138 - acc: 
0.2937 - val_loss: 62.3838 - val_acc: 0.6250
Epoch 2/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 66.8716 - acc: 
0.3167 - val_loss: 64.4628 - val_acc: 0.1875
Epoch 3/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 65.6411 - acc: 
0.2750 - val_loss: 96.1742 - val_acc: 0.1250
Epoch 4/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 70.4931 - acc: 
0.2875 - val_loss: 91.4954 - val_acc: 0.2031
Epoch 5/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 68.8988 - acc: 
0.1813 - val_loss: 75.3798 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 69.1241 - acc: 
0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 77.7191 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 64.7226 - acc: 
0.3479 - val_loss: 74.3400 - val_acc: 0.5156
Epoch 8/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 68.5523 - acc: 
0.1719 - val_loss: 69.1414 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 9/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 66.1609 - acc: 
0.7917 - val_loss: 70.9609 - val_acc: 0.8438
Epoch 10/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 68.6736 - acc: 
0.7552 - val_loss: 68.3616 - val_acc: 0.7344

Test-Accuracy: 0.4234375
```

What confuses me is how scattered and inconsistent my val_acc values are. Is this due to bad data or bad modeling?

Here is a snipit of my training data (It is syslog that i have parsed into key values)

```
syslog_data = [
[0.110002,0.4,0.2,0,0,0,5], [0.110002,0.4,0.2,0,0,0,5], [0.110002,0.4,0.1,0,0,0,5], [0.110002,0.4,0.2,0,0,0,5],
[0.302014,0,0,0,0.0,0,1], [0.302014,0,0,0,0.0,0,1], [0.302014,0,0,0,0.0,0,1], [0.302014,0,0,0,0.0,0,1],
[0.302014,0,0,0,0.0,0,1], [0.302014,0,0,0,0.0,0,1], [0.302014,0,0,0,0.0,0,1], [0.302014,0,0,0,0.0,0,1],
[0.419002,0.2,0.1,0,0,0,6], [0.419002,0.2,0.1,0,0,0,6], [0.419002,0.2,0.1,0,0,0,6], [0.419002,0.2,0.1,0,0,0,6],
[0.110002,0.4,0,0,0,0,5], [0.110002,0.4,0,0,0,0,5], [0.110002,0.4,0.1,0,0,0,5], [0.110002,0.4,0.2,0,0,0,5],
[0.305013,0.5,0,0,0,0,4], [0.305013,0.5,0,0,0,0,4], [0.305013,0.5,0,0,0,0,4], [0.305013,0.5,0,0,0,0,4],
[0.710003,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,8], [0.710003,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,8], [0.710003,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,8], [0.710003,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,8],
[0.302014,0,0,0,0.03,0.3,2], [0.302014,0,0,0,0.03,0.3,2], [0.302014,0,0,0,0.03,0.3,2], [0.302014,0,0,0,0.03,0.3,2],
```

And here is the code behind my NN

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from syslog import syslog_data, syslog_eval, syslog_pred

print(tf.VERSION)
print(tf.keras.__version__)

x = np.array([arr[:-1] for arr in syslog_data], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([arr[-1:] for arr in syslog_data], dtype=np.float32)

x_ev = np.array([arr[:-1] for arr in syslog_eval], dtype=np.float32)
y_ev = np.array([arr[-1:] for arr in syslog_eval], dtype=np.float32)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with x units to the model:
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(6,)))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
# Add a softmax layer with 8 output units:
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
dataset = dataset.batch(32).repeat()

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_ev, y_ev))
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(32).repeat()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

results = model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=30,
          validation_data=val_dataset,
          validation_steps=2)

x = np.array([arr[:-1] for arr in syslog_pred], dtype=np.float32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)

y = model.predict(x)
print(y)
print("Test-Accuracy:", np.mean(results.history["val_acc"]))
```

EDIT:

I have expanded my batch size to 2000 and get the following results:

```
Epoch 1/10
30/30 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 67.8644 - acc: 
0.1418 - val_loss: 62.3833 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 67.8003 - acc: 
0.0894 - val_loss: 64.4627 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 67.8639 - acc: 
0.2535 - val_loss: 96.1742 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 4/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 67.8003 - acc: 
0.4979 - val_loss: 91.4954 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 5/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 67.8639 - acc: 
0.1995 - val_loss: 75.3798 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 67.8003 - acc: 
0.4316 - val_loss: 77.7191 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 67.8639 - acc: 
0.4328 - val_loss: 74.3400 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 67.8002 - acc: 
0.7325 - val_loss: 69.1414 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 67.8639 - acc: 
0.8989 - val_loss: 70.9609 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 10/10
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 67.8002 - acc: 
0.9663 - val_loss: 68.3616 - val_acc: 1.0000
[[0.12500003 0.12500003 0.12500001 0.12500003 0.125      0.12499999
  0.12499997 0.12499999]]
Test-Accuracy: 0.4
```

Comment: Do you only have 30 training examples? If so, you're trying to learn an extremely large number of parameters from a very small number of examples, and that may account for the erratic behavior of your network.

Comment: I have 8k, ill expand that and give the results

Comment: Added in edit with expanded batch

Comment: Are you setting `steps_per_epoch` for time concerns? Depending on the `batch_size` you choose you aren't seeing the whole dataset in each epoch. Can you try setting the `batch_size` to a moderate number (32 or something) and not specifying the `steps_per_epoch` during training?

Comment: ValueError: When using iterators as input to a model, you should specify the `steps_per_epoch` argument

Comment: Ive changed the batch, epoch, steps to tons of different values. Im getting a mix of really really high accuracy and really low

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. It was a problem with my labels.

```
Epoch 1/10
100/100 [==============================] - 7s 66ms/step - loss: 2.0792 - acc: 0.2209 
- val_loss: 2.1252 - val_acc: 0.1250
Epoch 2/10
100/100 [==============================] - 6s 63ms/step - loss: 1.9951 - acc: 0.2380 
- val_loss: 1.7550 - val_acc: 0.3750
Epoch 3/10
100/100 [==============================] - 6s 64ms/step - loss: 1.1870 - acc: 0.6727 
- val_loss: 0.6140 - val_acc: 0.8750
Epoch 4/10
100/100 [==============================] - 6s 64ms/step - loss: 0.4538 - acc: 0.9728 
- val_loss: 0.3049 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 5/10
100/100 [==============================] - 5s 55ms/step - loss: 0.2086 - acc: 1.0000 
- val_loss: 0.1202 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 6/10
100/100 [==============================] - 6s 56ms/step - loss: 0.1060 - acc: 1.0000 
- val_loss: 0.0746 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 7/10
100/100 [==============================] - 7s 69ms/step - loss: 0.0633 - acc: 1.0000 
- val_loss: 0.0493 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 8/10
100/100 [==============================] - 7s 65ms/step - loss: 0.0423 - acc: 1.0000 
- val_loss: 0.0381 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 9/10
100/100 [==============================] - 6s 59ms/step - loss: 0.0305 - acc: 1.0000 
- val_loss: 0.0218 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 10/10
100/100 [==============================] - 6s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0232 - acc: 1.0000 
- val_loss: 0.0209 - val_acc: 1.0000
```